# Conver .flv to .mov using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, mov

I am trying to convert an flv file (recorded using red5 server) to .mov file using ffmpeg.

Using below code is actually making the video choppy. We can make out that from file size. flv file size is 1.45 MB whereas converted file .mov is 270 KB.

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv sample.mov
```

I don't have much knowledge about ffmpeg. Please let me know if I need to add any parameters to retain / improve the video quality.

Comment: This is probably because of video downsizing. Check if ffmpeg provides option to set video resolution & bitrate.

Comment: What is the recommended bit rate if I am recording the video at 20 FPS and 640x480?

Comment: Try to use the same bitrate and video resolution as that of source flv content. (Around 2-3 Mbps should be okay)

Comment: I tried this and seems like it retaining the video quality. ffmpeg -i input.flv -ar 22050 -qscale 4 -bufsize 20000k -b 3072 -s 640x480 sample.mov

Answer (score 0):

try this: `ffmpeg -i input.flv -ar 22050 -b 500 -s 320x240 sample.mov`

Comment: Tried this option but still the same quality. Output file size is arounf 25o KB now. Changed the resolution to 640x480 too.